# Using Python to write to HTML file with MySQL data as source?

Tags: python, mysql, html

I am trying to generate some simple html pages that contain data stored in a MySQL database. I have searched and searched for an answer to this and while I can successfully generate html pages from txt or user input I can't get it working with SQL. I am not worried about formatting the data in html or anything, that I can work out. All I would like to do is something like the following but I can't work out how to actually get the data printing to the file. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import MySQLdb 

def data():    
    db_connection = MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost', user='root', passwd='') 
    cursor = db_connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute('USE inb104')
    cursor.execute("SELECT Value FROM popularity WHERE Category = 'movies'")
    result = cursor.fetchall()

    return result

htmlFilename = 'test.html'
htmlFile = open(htmlFilename, 'w')
htmlFile.write = data
htmlFile.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

Change this:

```
htmlFile.write = data
```

to:

```
def formatDataAsHtml(data):
    return "<br>".join(data)

htmlFile.write(formatDataAsHtml(data()))
```

Comment: Thanks but I get an error saying: TypeError: must be string or read-only character buffer, not tuple

Answer (score 2):

```
def data():    
    db_connection = MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost', user='root', passwd='') 
    cursor = db_connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute('USE inb104')
    cursor.execute("SELECT Value FROM popularity WHERE Category = 'movies'")
    result = cursor.fetchall()

    return ' '.join(result)
```

If your `data()` returns a tuple, you may want to use `join` to make it into a string.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure to replace

```
return ' '.join(result)
```

with

```
list_of_strings = ["(%s)" % c for c in result]
return ' '.join(list_of_strings)
```